# Headers already sent by

Tags: errors

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /forums/vb/search/searchcontroller/version.php:91) in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 862
```

I am not sure what this error means. Can someone help me out?

Line 862 from functions.php is...

`setcookie( 'wp-settings-time-' . $user->ID, time(), time() + 31536000, SITECOOKIEPATH );`

If any other info is needed, please let me know.

Here are lines 77-95 from `version.php`:

```
//Çàïðîñ ê íàøåìó õîñòó_3 \ Êóðëû

function geturl_3($url)

{

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is some output in `/forums/vb/search/searchcontroller/version.php:91`. An `echo`, an empty line, an [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) or something similar.

PHP sends the response headers *before* the output starts, and it sends those headers just *once*. So you cannot send a session header later. That’s what the error message is telling you.

Remove the early output, and it’ll work again.

Comment: This is on `line 91` of `version.php`: `curl_close($ch);` Should I remove that?

Comment: No, there is probably a `curl_exec($ch);` somewhere before. `curl_close()` just sets these resources free. Without more context it’s hard to tell what to do. I would ask the author of the forum software.

Comment: Will do, but just in case it rings a bell, I added that whole function to the original post (lines 77-91). One thing I noticed was the comment above it on the first line. It looks like spam to me. Do you think it is?

Comment: Read what [`curl_exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) does when `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is set: It sends output to the browser. You could use `ob_start()` at the beginning of this function to avoid early headers. But this isn't exactly a clean way to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open your functions.php , and verify that there is NO empty spaces or lines BEFORE the first `<?php` tag and none BEHIND the last closing `?>` php tag. if this is not working, repeat the process for EACH theme file and plugin . that should fix your problem.